# WCF exception - "Service not found" when retrieving large collection

Tags: wcf, silverlight, web-services

my WCF service it's used by a Silverlight application to retrieve data. I've no problem,

```
    [OperationContract]
MyCollectionClass GetList(int sessID, string name);

  [CollectionDataContract]
public class MyCollectionClass : List<MyClass>{ }

  [DataContract]
public class MyClass {

  [DataMember]
  public string Prop1 { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string Prop2 { get; set; }
```

}

But.. when MyCollectionClass have a less then 3000+ "record" it works. When the number of records is greater the WCF service seems to work, but on the completed event of the Silverlight app an exception occurs: "Service Not Found".
I've found that could be related to service configuration and i've tryied to use both:

```
maxBufferSize="2147483647"
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
```

on WCF and Client configuration. Also added:

```
readerQuotas: 
  maxArrayLength="2000000" 
  maxStringContentLength="2000000"/>
```

(also changed the values found) But seems to not working. 
I think that the problem is that the message exceed the max number of byte per "message", but I do not understand why data is not spanned on different message. 
 Any tips is appreciated.

Giorgio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, in my case was just serializing an string and no prob there, BUT in your case you are serializing a big bunch of objects, there's a default limit for that, I remember I saw a post about that (just a setting in the config --> maxItemsInObjectGraph) to high up that number of serialized objects,

**Links**

http://silverlight.net/forums/t/17674.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1330713.aspx

**Settings:**

HTH
  Braulio

Comment: the section that made the trick is :
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

I have only managed the first 2 before. Now it works :D. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable wcf service logging on server side. This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use these 2 statement right after InitializeComponent:

binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5000000
binding.MaxBufferSize = 5000000

You can change the numbers to what you want but I had to do this in order to recieve a large amount of data on the Silverlgiht client.  My binding object is defines as:

Private binding As New BasicHttpBinding

This is in vb.net.  Works like a charm after I include these items.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/retrieving-huge-amount-of-data-from-wcf-service-in-silverlight-application/.

Answer (score 0):

I use silverlight 4 and vs 2010, and I had the same problem, and I resolved modifing the web.config file.

My original web.config file had:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

And I changed it by:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors> 
         <serviceBehaviors> 
             <behavior> 
                 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/> 
                 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/> 
                 <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>  <!--this very is important: it is the size of the buffer-->
             </behavior> 
         </serviceBehaviors> 
     </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest that you decrease the number of records you are returning? Not as a work around but as a usability suggestion. I cannot imagine any user coping with being shown 3000+ records. If you will be aggregating values from the data set rather aggregate them server side, it will boost your app's performance greatly... I have encountered this a couple of times in my apps, and almost always it worked out better to change the design than the options...

Comment: unfortunately it wasn't an option at that time.